# Getting Started - Viewing a Store

Tags: virtocommerce

Installed the platform.
Installed the Commerce bundle of modules.

Setup a couple catalogs

Setup a couple stores, one on default url and one on another url mapped to same Azure site.

Installed the timber theme on each.

The urls only show the login page. How do I get the stores to show up, the catalogs each have at least one product.

Comment: Have you installed the storefront?

Comment: Yeah that's a no, started with the Azure deploy from the vc-platform. Does the vc-storefront azure deploy then deploy the platform as well?

Seems like I should just destroy the resource group I created for the vc-platform and redeploy using the vc-storefront?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both platform and storefront which are two different web applications. 
Storefront connects to the platform and shows stores and products to customers, while platform is intended for managers, not for customers.